# Density profile in the atmosphere, which equations to use...?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, atmospheric-science, ideal-gas, density

I came across the following density profile in the atmosphere:

```
 T_0 = 288.16; %sea level temperature (kelvin)

 rho_0 = 1.225; %sea level density (kg/m^3)

 a = -0.0065; %lapse rate (K/m)

 R = 287.05; %gas constant (J/kg*K)

den = [];

for h = 1:11000

    T = T_0 + a*h;

    den(h) = rho_0 * (T/T_0)^((-g_0/(a*R)) - 1 );

end

T_isot = 217; %isothermal temp (K)

for h = 11001:13000

   den(h) = den(11000) * (exp(1))^((-g_0/(T_isot*R))* (h-11000));

end
```

Here's what I'm typically used to, derived form the ideal gas law:

$$p(h)=P(h)/(R*T(h))$$ where $$P(h) = P_0*exp(-(h/h_0))$$

My expression seems to be much simpler...so which ones do you like, and why? I'm trying to decide which to use in an experiment...
And what would you recommend for $T(h)$? as you can see, above they use a linear gradient and an isothermal assumption....

Comment: to what altitude do you need the atmosphere? the [US Standard Atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Standard_Atmosphere) is pretty good up to ~80 km, then you have to start dealing with weather, solar cycles, etc...

Comment: then I recommend implementing the 7-layer atmosphere using the 1976 US Standard Atmosphere, it's more than enough for most purposes in the lower atmosphere, unless you are doing detail design of a sounding rocket or something

Comment: I see, and that is an empirical collection of data? So even though it's been almost 40 years, those measurements still stand?

Comment: Yes, it's built off years of measurements from around the world. there has been no "official" US standard atmosphere update since then, though there have been other models released (but they are mostly concerned with altitudes >150km)

Comment: And what ails in the equations I provided. Is is that temperature is not really linear?

Comment: it just depends on what altitude you want to go to. An exponential atmosphere model can work, to be sure, but it is very simple to implement the model like in the USStdAtm. From 0-11km, you have the correct lapse rate, and from 11-13 km (but the isothermal layer continues all the way up to 32km).

Comment: So could I just linearly interpolate these points? As in: http://www.pdas.com/atmosTable1SI.html

Comment: The equations I've used to compute pressure and density are found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula). There is also a brief derivation of the equations at the end of the page

Answer (score 1):

I calculated the shape of the two expressions, and looked at the difference. I also plotted the difference if you used linear interpolation from the data in [the table you linked in the comments](http://www.pdas.com/atmosTable1SI.html) (data points shown in red dots on the first plot):

[image]

I suppose it all depends how much you care about the difference... 6% seems quite a big difference (it will be smaller over a smaller range; and I calculated `h_0` by fitting the data, and you might have a value that works better over a narrow range of heights). Clearly, even linear interpolation with data spaced by 2 km gives a much better agreement with the "complex" model; if you used a higher order interpolation (quadratic, cubic), the error would be tiny.

Incidentally in your Matlab code, the line

```
den(h) = den(11000) * (exp(1))^((-g_0/(T_isot*R))* (h-11000));
```

can of course be written as

```
den(h) = den(11000) * exp(-g_0/(T_isot*R) * (h-11000));
```

And as a further aside, you really want to initialize your Matlab arrays to the size you want them to end up as - otherwise, you will slow your code very significantly (it keeps resizing and potentially moving the array as it gets bigger). So just add

```
den = zeros(1,13000);
```

There are other ways to make that density calculation a lot more compact...

Comment: I was so confused looking at these plots, then I realized that altitude/height was the x-axis. Then I remembered that the plots we usually make are the opposite of "normal"

Comment: Sorry - I was using Python's `pyplot` which makes a mess when you label axes in a diagram with subplots. It doesn't appear to give enough space and you get overlapping text unless you make the diagram much bigger. I was plotting in the "usual" way - independent parameter along the X axis. Updated with the larger, labeled diagram...

Comment: no sweat, it's obvious what the graphs are conveying. what value did you get for `h0`? I've seen something like 7500 meters used for a large portion of the atmosphere

Comment: I got 7440 for $h_0$ - pretty close to the value you found. But even when I use the value of $T$ from the same table, I don't get a very good agreement with the data - interpolating the table just seems to be better...

Comment: What lapse rate did you use for the "complex" plot?

Comment: So the complex represents the matlab code I presented, versus the "simple" equation I presented? And the "delta simple" and "delta interp" are comparing which ones (both of those analytical to the data table?)? I want to make sure I understand what each term on the axis represents.